# C++ toString() with sprintf()

Tags: c++, string, tostring, printf, c-str

With C++ I am trying to implement a toString() function for my class:

```
void ClassName::toString(string& returnString)
{
    sprintf(returnString.c_str(), "Position: (%f, %f, %f)\n", position.x, position.y, position.y);
}
```

However I keep getting this error: **argument of type const char* is incompatible with parameter of type char***

How do I fix this and make the argument no longer const?

Answer (score 5):

> How do I fix this?

Use a different approach, use a `stringstream` instead or an auxiliary buffer.

```
void ClassName::toString(string& returnString)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Position: (" << position.x << ", " << position.y << ", " 
       << position.z << ")\n");
    returnString = ss.str();
}
```

> and make the argument no longer const?

**Don't.** Hell will break lose if you change `c_str` to a non-const type. Fellow programmers will weep. Angels will lose their wings. Kittens will die. Oil prices will rise. Stock-market crashes. Zombie apocalipse.

**It's `const` for a reason** - so you don't modify it. Doing so would result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: `Hell will break lose ` luv it! :)

Comment: Ahhhhh. No need for a toString(). Just define a stream operator for the class. You can then use lexial_cast<> to do the conversion if you actually need a string but usually the only reason for toString() is to print it so stream operator works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In modern C++ you could say:

```
std::string ClassName::toString() const
{
    return "Position: (" + std::to_string(position.x) + ", "
          + std::to_string(position.y) + ", "
          + std::to_string(position.z) + ")\n";
}
```

If you must use `printf`, you can still use a string, but you have to resize it first.

```
std::string ClassName::toString() const
{
    static const int initial_size = 1024;

    std::string s(initial_size);
    int ret = std::snprintf(&s[0], s.size(), "Position: (%f, %f, %f)\n", position.x, position.y, position.y);
    s.resize(ret);

    // handle overflow: print again
    if (s.size() > initial_size)
    {
        std::snprintf(&s[0], s.size(), "Position: (%f, %f, %f)\n", position.x, position.y, position.y);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Note that `&s[0]` gives you a pointer to mutable char, and indeed to the first element of a whole array of those of size `s.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

`c_str()` returns a `const char *` because it is generally not a good idea to change the value of the string using the pointer returned by `c_str()` function.

What you are trying to do is pointless by the way. You should simply use `returnString.append()` method.

But if you must do it with sprintf, you should make sure your string has the space to hold the output of sprintf.

**First method:** You can do it with `.reserve()` method, but it will not change the string's internal size counter which is returned by `.size()` if you directly modify the string buffer with `sprintf()` method (`append()` will do the proper size adjustment). There will not be any problems if you do not need to use the `.size()` method as far as I know.

**Second method (better):** This is the better way to go if you know the exact output length of the sprintf. You should call `.resize()` method instead of `.reserve()`. `.resize()` will properly adjust string's size counter.

Finally, you should use: `sprintf(const_cast<char *>(returnString.data()), ...`

This whole thing is not a good idea by the way.

**P.S.**
`.data()` is the same as `.**c**_str()` except it does not append null terminator to make it c-style string.

Answer (score 0):

Make a buffer for sprintf. Then assign to returnString back.

```
void ClassName::toString(string& returnString)
{ 
    char buffer[64] = {}; // expect the length of `Position Info` will not exceed 63
    sprintf(buffer, "Position: (%f, %f, %f)\n", position.x, position.y, position.y);
    returnString = buffer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

> The returned array points to an internal location with the required storage space for this sequence of characters plus its terminating null-character, but the values in this array should not be modified in the program and are only guaranteed to remain unchanged until the next call to a non-constant member function of the string object.

you are not allowed to modify the content of that returned char *

try something like:

```
void ClassName::toString(string& returnString)
{
    char tmp[256];
    sprintf(tmp, "Position: (%f, %f, %f)\n", position.x, position.y, position.y);
    returnString=tmp;
}
```